# SVD confusion for matrices $m\times n$ with $m>n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition, svd

According to my understanding, the SVD decomposition consists of decomposing a matrix into a rotation, scaling, then another rotation. This suggests to me one can use that to create arbitrary linear transformations. This is what I am attempting to do.

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 3}$ be a matrix defined from its SVD decomposition as a rotation (with $z$ as axis), then unitary scaling and finally an identity matrix, that is:

$$A=I_{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}R_z^T
$$

where $I_2$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix, and

$$R_z=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

That yields:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

If we consider $Av$, then the $z$ component of $v$ has no influence over $Av$. Intuitively that just seems wrong; I know $z$ won't rotate since that is the axis of rotation, but it is just gone. How to make intuitive sense of this?

Comment: With this matrix $A$ you map a vector in 3D to a 2D space. In a 2D space, the $z$ component does not exist. Intuitively, consider this as projecting a 3D object into a plane, like a piece of paper or a computer display.

Comment: Yes, but in general it seems to me that because of the form of the singular values matrix, the $z$ axis will never affect. The $z$ always get multiplied by $0$.

Comment: @S Here's one intuitive explanation: the diagonal transformation 
$$
\pmatrix{\sigma_1 & 0&0\\0& \sigma_2 & 0}
$$
only "sees" the xy plane. If you want a linear transformation that depends on the $z$-coordinate, the initial rotation must involve some interaction between the $z$-axis and the $xy$ plane so that the $z$-coordinate is "brought into" the $xy$-plane projection of the point. Your rotation about the $z$-axis has no such interaction.